# Passive verb that means "to falsely declare someone to be a liar"?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

I am looking for a single verb that means "to declare (one) a liar" or "to accuse (one) of being a liar" - a verb that can take an agent. For example, I could replace "was declared a lair" in the following sentence with the passive form of this verb:

> She gave a convincing testimony, but *was declared a liar* by the prosecutor.

It needs to have a negative connotation, like the verb "to allege". In other words, the agent is falsely accusing the subject of being a liar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be **exposed**?

Comment: @WeatherVane perhaps I should edit my question. I am looking for something with more of a negative connotation. The subject is being falsely accused by the agent.

Comment: If it's not true, then *framed*? *Misrepresented*? However, none of those mean *liar* specifically. I don't think you'll find a single word that fits.

Comment: **allege** does not impute anything untoward with respect to the person bringing the allegation.

Comment: Perhaps, “she was ***discredited*** by the prosecutor.”

Comment: You could say they are defamatory, but it has a wider meaning then just lying. Agree with Justin Bassford

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good use for the word **traduce**!

> "She gave a convincing testimony, but **was traduced** a liar by the
>   prosecutor." (Past Indefinite, Passive Voice)

**traduce**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/traduce?family=traduced)

> to expose to contempt; to bring discredit upon; to dishonour, to disgrace; to malign

and [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/204319#eid17873810):

> To pervert, corrupt, misrepresent, falsify; to turn into something bad

As in:

> Instead, my reputation was traduced, my story distorted, my
>   credibility made hostage to smears. The Guardian Apr 19, 2018

and

> The senator believed he been traduced by those who seized upon his
>   controversial comment. Economist May 13, 2018

Synonyms: badmouth, drag through the mud, malign

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. The meaning of "traduce" is to malign some, not to declare someone a liar. If someone calls someone else a liar, they are traducing that person, but the reverse is not necessarily true - I can traduce someone as being incompetent or foolish without describing their honesty. Great word, though.

Comment: Traduce, you say! (Sorry, couldn't help myself.) {Okay, yes I could...}

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's so good it's a keeper!

Comment: Only if you want to force readers to dig up the dictionary. This word is *extremely* uncommon.

Comment: @jpmc26 About 11% of all non-obsolete OED entries are in Band 4. extremely uncommon?

Comment: I think this is just wrong.  The lawyer did not pervert, corrupt, misrepresent or falsify.

Comment: The correct usage would be “traduced _as_ a liar” I believe.

Comment: @NeilW concur ... as is implied

Answer (score 2):

If the accusation is not necessarily false, you could use **label**, or for a more strongly negative connotation, **brand** or **denounce**.

> She gave a convincing testimony, but was *denounced as*/*branded* a liar by the prosecutor.

Otherwise, there are a host of words meaning "to falsely accuse" which may be appropriate here.

**Slander**, **defame**, **calumniate**, **asperse**, **malign**, **smear** in addition to **traduce** mentioned elsewhere.

> She gave a convincing testimony, but was *maligned*/*calumniated* as a liar by the prosecutor.

Of these, **traduce**, **asperse** and **calumniate** are less likely to be understood.

Here's an interesting comparison of a number of these words from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malign):

> **malign**, **traduce**, **asperse**, **vilify**, **calumniate**, **defame**, **slander** mean to injure by speaking ill of. **Malign** suggests specific and often subtle misrepresentation but may not always imply deliberate lying: *the most maligned monarch in British history*. **Traduce** stresses the resulting ignominy and distress to the victim: *so traduced the governor that he was driven from office*. **Asperse** implies continued attack on a reputation often by indirect or insinuated detraction: *both candidates aspersed the other's motives*. **Vilify** implies attempting to destroy a reputation by open and direct abuse: *no criminal was more vilified in the press*. **Calumniate** imputes malice to the speaker and falsity to the assertions: *falsely calumniated as a traitor.* **Defame** stresses the actual loss of or injury to one's good name: *sued them for defaming her reputation*. **Slander** stresses the suffering of the victim: *town gossips slandered their good name*.

Answer (score -1):

**refute**

> "She gave a convincing testimony, which was refuted by the prosecutor."

> **refute**
>   VERB
>   **1** Prove (a statement or theory) to be wrong or false; disprove.
>   *‘these claims have not been convincingly refuted’*
>   [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refute)

Comment: This doesn't mean "**falsely** accusing" someone, as the question asks.